# Code Styling with Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, coding-style, reformatting

Let's say I have code that looks like this:

```
public abstract class
    ResourceDownloaderBaseImpl
    implements ResourceDownloader {

    public Object
       getProperty(
           String name)

            throws ResourceDownloaderException {
    ....
```

And bunch of other. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in Intellij IDEA it does not format it into single line like this:

```
public abstract class ResourceDownloaderBaseImpl implements ResourceDownloader {

    public Object getProperty(String name) throws ResourceDownloaderException {
    ...
```

Is there a way to adjust the code reformating feature so it puts the signatures onto a single line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the `Code Style` section in your `Project Settings` where you can specify almost everything.
More precisely, look under `Code Style` - `Wrapping and bracing` and see whether `keep line breaks during reformatting`is switched on

[image]